# How can I prevent having multiple combinations of Firestore Indexes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Basically, I have a query from Firestore, and some of the filter fields may be empty, in that case the specific query will be ignored,Since inequality queries with multiple fields requires indexes, what's the best way to create indexes of such query without going through all possible combinations.

e.g, 'country' and 'budget_high', 'gender' and 'budget_high', 'age' and 'budget_high', 'country, gender' and 'budget_high' and so on.

This is my query.

```js
if (country !== "") query = query.where("country", "==", country);
  if (gender !== "") query = query.where("gender", "==", gender);
  if (age !== "") query = query.where("age", "==", age);
  if (religion !== "") query = query.where("religion", "==", religion);
  if (budget_high !== "") query = query.where("budget_high", "<=", Number(budget_high));
  return query
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      var data = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        let user_data = doc.data();
        user_data.created_at = `${user_data.created_at.toDate()}`;
        data.push(user_data);
      });
      return data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
      return [];
    });
};
```

Here are my Single Field Exemptions for collection (not collection group)
[image]

Comment: Have you checked [How can I create indexes for different combinations of fields in Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52992525/13130697)

Comment: @Dharmaraj yes I've checked, that question was for trying to create the indexes while mine is trying to prevent them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, we need a field that will be present in all queries. You can orderBy one of the fields inorder for it to always be present (budget_high in this case since you are calling inequality query on it).

So create 4 composite indexes.

1. budget_high and country ASC
2. budget_high and gender ASC
3. budget_high and age ASC
4. budget_high and religion ASC

This will effectively handle your query combinations.

Read the [merging index docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#taking_advantage_of_index_merging)

Comment: you mean single field exemptions ?, because I created composite indexes and sell didn't work.

Comment: Yes, these 5 single field exemptions.

Comment: Wait... single field indexes... not single field exemptions (and not for collection group). You can read the docs I attached.

Comment: I already read the documentation,I still can't figure it out. you can only create exemptions on single field indexes tab, I already created for collection(not group) and it's still not working. I also attached an image you can see.

Comment: Okay. what do you want to order the result with? Let’s assume it’s x. So now, you create 5 composite indexes, x and country, x and gender, x and age, x and religion, x and budget_high. All can be ASC. Then run your query.

Comment: still didn't work,It will only work if all the inputs are inserted that way, meaning if I all the fields != '', otherwise I would have to create composite indexes for all combinations with budget_high field since it uses inequality (<=). which was the whole point of my questions, trying not to do that.

Comment: Wait, I want to be sure you understand what I am suggesting. Something like this: budget_high and country, budget_high and gender, budget_high and age, budget_high and religion. 4 composite indexes, all ASC. You did this and it didn’t work? This will be only 4 indexes (which is less than trying all possible combinations)

Comment: Glad I could help. I have updated my answer based on our discussions.

Comment: Hello, me again, I can't seem to add orderBy("timestamp","desc"), it says I need to create a separate composite index, Can you update your answer covering this also.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @Peter O. response, the order of the fields in the indexes is important. Please try the following:

1. country ASC and budget_high
2. gender ASC and budget_high
3. age ASC and budget_high
4. religion ASC and budget_high

I hope this helps.